# How to print in my class like tree command in unix?

Tags: java, unix, tree, treeview, composite

I am trying really hard to make my code to print the files and the directories in the same way that the command 'tree' in unix print.

What do I need to do so it will work? I'm stuck on it to much hours :(

This is the class I created for simple implementation of tree command using the composite design pattern:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TreePrint {
    private final Directory root;

    public TreePrint(String path) {
        root = new Directory(path);
    }

    public void printTree(){
        root.print(0);
    }

    private interface FileSystemComponent {
        void print(int level);
    }

    private static class FileComponent implements FileSystemComponent{
        private final String fileName;

        public FileComponent(String name) {
            fileName = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void print(int level) {
            printLevel(level);
            System.out.println(fileName);
        }
    }

    private static class Directory implements FileSystemComponent{
        private final String directoryName;
        private final List<FileSystemComponent> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

        public Directory(String path) {
            File directory = new File(path);
            if(!directory.exists()){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid path, please try again");
            }

            directoryName = directory.getName();
            File[] components = directory.listFiles();

            if(null != components) {
                for (File file : components) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        fileList.add(new Directory(file.getPath()));
                    } else {
                        fileList.add(new FileComponent(file.getName()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void print(int level) {
            printLevel(level);
            System.out.println(colorTextToBlue(directoryName));
            for(FileSystemComponent file : fileList) {
                file.print(level + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printLevel(int level){
        System.out.print("├──");
        for (int i = 0; i < level; ++i) {
            System.out.print("──");
        }
    }

    private static String colorTextToBlue(String text){
        final String blueBold = "\033[1;34m";
        final String reset = "\033[0m";

        return blueBold + text + reset;
    }
}
```

For example, I want to print like this:

```
├── makefile
├── quiz19.c
├── stack_min.c
└── stack_min.h
```

but it's print like this:

```
├──quiz19
├────makefile
├────quiz19.c
├────stack_min.c
├────stack_min.h
```

(I still wan't the root on top, but i just want the lines to be the same like int the last file)

Comment: Please be more specific than “What do I need to do so it will work?”  What about the program’s behavior is different from what you were expecting?

Comment: add the comparison

Comment: I gather you want the last line to print `└──` rather than `├──`?